# Calling a defined method results in NameError

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code:

```
def findExact(myList):
    # Find the "exact" dictionary entry in a list of dictionaries.
    for thisDict in myList:
        if thisDict.get('exact') != None:
            return thisDict.get('exact')


def grabData(jsonFile):
    temp = []
    processThis = jsonFile['rows']

    for item in processThis:
        print('Created.....%s' % item['created'])
        print('Updated.....%s' % item['updated'])
        print('Title.......%s' % item['document']['title'][0])
        print('Tag.........%s' % item['tags'])
        print('Value.......%s' % findExact(item['target'][0]['selector']))
        print('URL.........%s' % item['target'][0]['source'])
        print('*****')
```

When I run it, I get `NameError: name 'findExact' is not defined`.  I don't understand what's the problem, I defined the function before I called it.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Your indentation might have something to do with it - can you edit your question to make sure that the indentation as we see it on StackOverflow is the same as it is in your code?

Comment: After indenting the first `for`-loop, no such error occured...

Comment: I corrected the indentation so it matches what's in my code.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Please make a [mcve] including the full error message. Where you said it's a method, that makes me think it's a class, but you didn't include the class statement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was calling grabData from outside the class and when I added the class to the call (i.e. MyClass.findExact), it started to work.